# The limit at infinity of a function in $L^2$

Tags: limits, lp-spaces

Suppose that $f'$ is locally absolutely continuous and $f$, $f''$ $ \in L^{2}(0,\infty)$

> Prove that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}[f^{2}(x)+2f(x)f'(x)+f'^{2}(x)]=0.$$

Actually, I proved that the limit exists but could not prove that it should be zero.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hint: using the assumption on $f,f'$ and the integral

$$
\int_0^x \frac{d}{dt}(f(t)+f'(t))^2dt
$$

show that the limit is finite. Then argue that if the limit is not 0, then at least one between $f$ and $f'$ cannot be in $L^2$.

Edit: The function $g=f^2+ff'+f'^2\geq 0$ is in $L^1(0,\infty)$ because $f,f'$ are in $L^2(0,\infty)$. Now, $g$ being integrable does not imply that the limit of $g$ at infinity is zero, since the limit may not exist; it does however imply that the $\lim\inf$ at infinity is zero. In particular, if you know that the limit exists, then it must be zero (since it must equal the $\lim\inf$). To show this, argue by contradiction: if the limit is, say, $c>0$, then, for $x$ large enough, say $x>M$, $g(x)>c/2>0$. But then, $\int_M^\infty g(x)$...

Comment: Actually, I agree with you in the existence of the limit as finite but I could not prove that it should be zero...more help please in this part.

Comment: I added an edit. I hope it helps.

Comment: $f''$ is in $L^2(0,\infty)$ and $f'$ is only absolutely continuous as the original question say...Does this change any thing in the proof?

Comment: Since $f,f''$ are in $L^2$, using integration by parts, you can show that $f'$ is also in $L^2$...

Comment: You are right and thanks for all your help.